# Error related to deviceScaleFactor

Tags: puppeteer

So just using https://try-puppeteer.appspot.com/

This code works fine:

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.goto('http://demo.spoonthemes.net/themes/couponis/');
await page.setViewport({width: 1280, height: 978, deviceScaleFactor: 1});


await page.screenshot({path: 'example2.jpg'});

await browser.close();
```

But if I change deviceScaleFactor to 2 (because I'm on a retina screen) I get this error: Error running your code. Error: Protocol error (Page.captureScreenshot): Target closed.

Any ideas why? Seems to work if I change the URL to example.com as well, but not if I try other websites.

Answer (score 2):

This error no longer appears as of Puppeteer v1.5.0.

The website that you were trying to access had `maximum-scale=1` in the source code:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

Therefore, `deviceScaleFactor: 2` appears to have been failing due to this fact.